# Can CFSWITCH prevent SQL injection when used for a sort column?

Tags: coldfusion, sql-injection

I use the following technique to ensure that any sort column params coming from the client go through a ListFindNoCase() function:

```
<cfif ListFindNoCase("date,score", params.order) EQ 0>
   <cfset params.order = "date">
</cfif>
```

This way, any sort column request gets vetted against the list values before being sent to the server. I then added the following code to my function:

```
<cfswitch expression="#params.order#">
   <cfcase value="date">
      <cfset params.order = "date DESC">
   </cfcase>
   <cfcase value="score">
      <cfset params.order = "score ASC">
   </cfcase>
   <cfdefaultcase>
      <cfset params.order = "date DESC">
   </cfdefaultcase>
</cfswitch>
```

Since default case will always set order to "date DESC" if the expression does not match the first two cases, doesn't that render ListCaseNoFind() redundant?

I wanted to make sure that this is true before I removed the ListFindNoCase() function!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, that is safe.  You're hardcoding the order by, so there is no chance that extraneous SQL can be injected.

Comment: This is also considered "white-listing" which is safe.